# Como configurar o ReSharper para NÃO adicionar comentários 'summary'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Ao utilizar a função do ReSharper (StyleCop) 'Remove Unused Directives in File' ou 'Remove Redundant Code in File' para excluir alguma biblioteca do meu projeto, o ReSharper a remove, porém adiciona comentários por todo o projeto, no estilo:

```
//   
// </copyright>
// <summary>
//   
// </summary>
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Já procurei diversos tutoriais de como desabilitar essa interação, porém até agora não achei nada que realmente funcione. Coisas que já tentei:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771356/stylecop-resharper-configuration-to-not-add-comments
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818358/style-cop-resharper-control-comments
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611346/how-to-globally-disable-file-headers-documentation-in-resharper-plugin-for-visua
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271881/remove-header-summary-stylecop

Entre outros..

Alguém poderia ajudar em como desabilitar esta funcionalidade?

Grato, desde já!

Comment: E esse? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271881/remove-header-summary-stylecop

Comment: Esse é semelhante ao procedimento do primeiro link que adicionei.. Já tentei desmarcar todas as opções do StyleCop após criar um usuário e ativa-lo, porém sem sucesso. Obrigado pela resposta, se tiver mais alguma sugestão, me mande por favor!

Comment: Você tentou alterar o File Header Text?

Comment: Já sim.. Inclusive o meu File Header Text esta limpo, sem nenhum texto.

Comment: Estranho.. é que atualmente meu workflow é Java, mas quando eu programava C# e usava o Resharper ele por padrão nem adicionava os summarys por isso achei estranho.

Comment: É realmente muito estranho, existe um desenvolvedor do meu setor que não tem isso habilitado (aparentemente ele não fez nada). Já tentei reinstalar o meu StyleCop como tentativa de resolução, mas até agora nada.

Comment: E reinstalar o resharper?

Comment: Também sem exito.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após alguns dias de teste e buscando novas formas de tentar resolver o problema, consegui solucionar o problema desabilitando as duas opções de comentário abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, desabilitei as opções de "Supress" nas mesmas configurações, porém tenho certeza se o mesmo influenciou na solução.

Se alguém não conseguiu, ou conseguiu de uma maneira diferente solucionar esse problema, por favor, publique.

Comment: Para desabilitar o "Supress" do StyleCop no ReSharper, utilizei o seguinte tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/enabling-or-disabling-source-analysis-rules.aspx

É antigo, porém fornece a lógica necessária nas versões atuais.

Comment: ah, mas summary é tão legal...rsrsrs kkk

Comment: kkkk Quando se esta num projeto de 2000 linhas, ele já não se torna tão legal assim rsrsrs :P

Comment: Só 2mil ? rs Número de linhas não é de muita importancia...talvez seja até falha na sua arquitetura, já que você possui classes com muitas responsabilidades :)

Comment: Realmente pode ser esse o caso.. (2000 foi um exemplo, já que o ReSharper adiciona os comentários sob todas as classes).